# How to define a non-equal constraint in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, constraints

I want to define a constraint for an optimization problem according which one of the variables should not be equal to a specific integer like 2.
I know we can use

```
function [c,ceq] = confuneq(x)
% Nonlinear inequality constraints
c = -x(1)*x(2) - 10;
% Nonlinear equality constraints
ceq = x(1)^2 + x(2) - 1;
```

for inequality and equality constraint but I cannot understand how to for example define x(1)~=x(2).

Thanks,

Comment: I think the problem here is that MATLAB is a computer language, meaning it requires numerical data to work with. The set of real numbers excluded 2 is infinitely large and thus MATLAB can't handle that, since it requires a finite number of input elements.

Comment: Are you doing this in the case of linear programming?  If that's the case, check this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37075/how-can-not-equals-be-expressed-as-an-inequality-for-a-linear-programming-model - However, using not-equals will make the search region non-convex and will have open regions.

Comment: Could you solve once for `x(1)>2`, once for `x(1)<2` then see which solution is best?

Comment: I am actually using `ga` and the expected output is something like: `X = [1, 2, 3, ....n]` and non of X's integers are equal to each other. However, while MATLAB is run, some of integers are repetitive i.e. `X = [1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, ...n]`. I want to impose a constraint like: `X(1) ~= X(2) ~= X(3) ~= ... X(n)`